# How to put value of textarea in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, textarea

How to load content into a textarea using spring mvc, for example - from database ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167859/spring-mvc-form-textarea-initial-contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an MVC Controller with an method that returns a ModelAndView with an attribute that is contains the content and write a JSP Pages (the view from ModelAndView) that uses creates a text area with the attribute from the Modell

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo/**")
class Demo{

   @Request
   public ModelAndView() {
      ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
      modelMap.putAttribute("content", "Hello World, this is a sunny day...");
      return new ModelAndView("demoView", modelMap);
   }
}
```

demoView.jsp

```
...
<textarea name="input" cols="50" rows="10"><c:out value="content"/></textarea>
...
```